# IOS - notification panel custom media player widget

Tags: ios, iphone, media-player, avplayer

I am new to iOS. I am trying to put a custom media player widget in notification panel but couldn't find any solution online. I request users to provide a code sample to guide me in the right path please. I am already using AVPlayer for playing media in my app.

[image: Like this]

Regards

Comment: hello, do  you get any solution for this?

Comment: No. not yet. I couldn't find any solution for this yet

Comment: Any solution yet?

Comment: unfortunately not